# Can't show log from Spring Cloud Vault Connection

Tags: spring, logging, cloud, vault

Due to an upgrade from spring 2.3.X to 2.4.X I had to upgrade the dependencies spring-cloud-starter-vault-config to 3.0.1.
This have a breaking change about the usage of bootstrap.yml file. (for detail -> https://spring.io/blog/2020/12/22/spring-cloud-2020-0-0-aka-ilford-is-available)

Have done the change and it's working fine however I don't have anymore any log about the connection to the vault server...

For example if I set my vault_token = "wrong_pwd" I used to have

```
12:13:17.853 [reactor-http-nio-1] WARN  o.s.v.a.ReactiveLifecycleAwareSessionManager - Cannot enhance VaultToken to a LoginToken: Token self-lookup: Status 403 Forbidden permission denied; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden from GET https://vault-decatec.pp.dktapp.cloud:443/v1/auth/token/lookup-self
```

Now I have nothing except of course some missing env var ...

I search a long time and try to change the logging level but I can't find a solution.
I don't want to let it like that because if there is an issue I will not be able to know the root cause easily. It could be the token expiration, the vault server unavailability, a missing key, etc...

Do you have a solution/idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can enable logging for the secret being requested with the following log level:

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        vault:
          core:
            env: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer directly by creating an issue on the github spring vault.

from nkvaratskhelia :
You can use the

> spring.cloud.vault.fail-fast=true

property. If there's something wrong with the connection, vault will report it and the application won't start.